# c++ fatal error C1001 on using variadic template

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, variadic

Hi everybody. Compiling my code I came upon the next error:
**fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.**

When I pass only one parameter to "exec" function, everything is ok. But when I pass more then one parameters it issues an error. I use vs 2015 and visual c++ compiler respectively.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
//using namespace std;

template <class T>
void param_push_(T arg, char ** param) {
  sprintf(*param, "%15.15e", arg);
}

template <class T, class... args>
void param_push_(T first, args... args, char ** param) {
  static int param_No = 0;
  sprintf(param[param_No++], "%15.15e", first);
  param_push(args..., param[param_No]);
}

template <class ... param_types>
void exec(const char * command, const param_types& ...param_values) {

  int arg_count = sizeof...(param_values);
  char ** params = new char*[arg_count];
  for (int i = 0; i < arg_count; ++i) {
    params[i] = new char[22 * sizeof(char)];
  }

  param_push_(param_values..., params); //cast parameters to (char *)  

  for (int i = 0; i < arg_count; ++i) {
    delete[] params[i];
  }
  delete[] params;

}

int main()
{
  double e_restriction = 0.55300000000000000000124124;
  double M_restriction = 5;

  exec("SELECT \"M\",e from orbital WHERE e < $1::double precision AND \"M\" < $2::double precision", e_restriction,M_restriction);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Internal error" means that this is a compiler bug, regardless the validity of your code. Under normal conditions the compiler should either compile the code or print a more sensible error.

Comment: Try to rename the function "exec" to something else. Just a guess. Should not cause a problem with MS but who knows. Other than that look on some MS resource as it is a compiler problem.

Comment: Tried with gcc. In the declaration of `param_push_`, try to use a name for `args` different from its type. E.g. `args... args_` instead of `args... args` (and change the call to `param_push` 3 lines after accordingly). Nothing more with clang

Comment: When I compile that with VS2015 I get : `error C2660: 'param_push_': function does not take 3 arguments`. Just could reproduce it. Adding another value causes the problem.

Comment: I changed name of "args" parameter and fixed function name  "param_push" when recursion is being called. Now I also get: error C2660: 'param_push_': function does not take 3 arguments

Comment: Thanks to Adrian Colomitchi. I see now, that my old template function tryed to call itself recursively with the other parameters' specifications, so it required another specification of a function. Functor allows us to make a new object of a new class, template specification of which satisfy new parameters pack and then do what we want calling operator().

Comment: @ArtemZefirov Your welcome and congrats for managing the homework. For the benefit of others, I suggest to edit the question and append (after a ---- hr) your comment there (skip the thanks, tho, I already received them): the comment is too low on the list to be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...> struct param_push;

template <class H, class... T>
struct param_push<H,T...> {
   void operator() (H head, T... tail, char** param) {
     sprintf(param[0], "%15.15e", head);
     param_push<T...> one_less;
     one_less(tail..., &param[1]);
   }
};

template <>
struct param_push<> {
  void operator() (char** param) {
    // does nothing, no more args to sprintf
  }
};

template <class ... param_types>
void exec(const char * command, const param_types& ...param_values) {

  int arg_count = sizeof...(param_values);
  char ** params = new char*[arg_count];
  for (int i = 0; i < arg_count; ++i) {
    params[i] = new char[22 * sizeof(char)];
  }

  // param_push_(param_values..., params); //cast parameters to (char *)
  struct param_push<param_types...> functor;
  functor(param_values..., params);

  for (int i = 0; i < arg_count; ++i) {
    std::cout << params[i] << " will be deleted" << std::endl;
    delete[] params[i];
  }
  delete[] params;

}

int main()
{
  double e_restriction = 0.55300000000000000000124124;
  double M_restriction = 5;

  exec("SELECT \"M\",e from orbital WHERE e < $1::double precision AND \"M\" < $2::double precision", e_restriction,M_restriction);

  return 0;
}
```

<sub>(and now, homework for Arty Zefirov: find the reason why when using template struct functors the technique works, why it fails for templated functions and update your question with the findings)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here's the output from an attempt to compile this code on gcc:

```
12 : error: declaration of 'args ... args'
void param_push_(T first, args... args, char ** param) {
^
11 : error: shadows template parm 'class ... args'
template <class T, class... args>
^
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116729-61-oaaqho/example.cpp: In function 'void param_push_(T, args ..., char**)':
12 : error: declaration of 'args ... args'
void param_push_(T first, args... args, char ** param) {
^
11 : error: shadows template parm 'class ... args'
template <class T, class... args>
^
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116729-61-oaaqho/example.cpp: In instantiation of 'void exec(const char*, const param_types& ...) [with param_types = {double, double}]':
41 : required from here
27 : error: no matching function for call to 'param_push_(const double&, const double&, char**&)'
param_push_(param_values..., params); //cast parameters to (char *)
^
7 : note: candidate: template<class T> void param_push_(T, char**)
void param_push_(T arg, char ** param) {
^
7 : note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
27 : note: cannot convert 'param_values#1' (type 'const double') to type 'char**'
param_push_(param_values..., params); //cast parameters to (char *)
^
12 : note: candidate: template<class T, class ... args> void param_push_(T, args ..., char**)
void param_push_(T first, args... args, char ** param) {
^
12 : note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
27 : note: cannot convert 'param_values#1' (type 'const double') to type 'char**'
param_push_(param_values..., params); //cast parameters to (char *)
^
Compilation failed
```

And you may want to re-think this:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
void param_push_(T first, Args... args, char ** param) {

  //
  // WARNING: param_No will be a different variable for each
  // combination of Args...
  //
  static int param_No = 0;

  sprintf(param[param_No++], "%15.15e", first);
  param_push(args..., param[param_No]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a new code. Template function doesn't mutch the current arguments. But it should do, doesn't it?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
//using namespace std;

template <class T>
void param_push_(T arg, char ** param) {
  sprintf(*param, "%15.15e", arg);
}

template <class T, class... args>
void param_push_(T first, args... args_temp, char ** param) {
  static int param_No = 0;
  sprintf(param[param_No++], "%15.15e", first);
  param_push_(args_temp..., param[param_No]);
}

template <class ... param_types>
void my_exec(const char * command, const param_types& ...param_values) {

  int arg_count = sizeof...(param_values);
  char ** params = new char*[arg_count];
  for (int i = 0; i < arg_count; ++i) {
    params[i] = new char[22 * sizeof(char)];
  }

  param_push_(param_values..., params); //cast parameters to (char *)  

  for (int i = 0; i < arg_count; ++i) {
    delete[] params[i];
  }
  delete[] params;

}

int main()
{
  double e_restriction = 0.55300000000000000000124124;
  double M_restriction = 5;
  param_push_<double, double, char**>;
  my_exec("SELECT \"M\",e from orbital WHERE e < $1::double precision AND \"M\" < $2::double precision", 
    e_restriction, M_restriction);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "But it should do, doesn't it?" - no, it should not. Hint: template functions don't allow partial specialization.